# Responder ou comentar em perguntas antigas

Tags: debate, perguntas

É permitido responder questões antigas, que inclusive possuem respostas bem votadas e aceitas?

Exemplo: [Como descriptografar MD5?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41517/como-descriptografar-md5)

Nesse caso específico, senti falta de um termo muito popular referente a "decodificação" de strings MD5, que é "rainbow table".

As respostas são ótimas, não tem nada de errado, mas achei estranho não incluírem esse termo em nenhuma das respostas apesar de terem comentado.

Comment: Talvez neste caso como só é um aparte se justifique um comentário na pergunta. Mas em todo caso não tem nada de mal respoder a perguntas antigas. Aconteceu comigo no SOen de me reponderem passado dois anos e eu até mudei a resposta certa para essa resposta. [Vê aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817521/edittext-view-with-keyboard-number-only)

Comment: Eu já fiz isto, do meu ponto de vista, desde que seja algo que complemente ou seja do seu ponto de vista no minimo melhor que as respostas atuais é valido sim :)

Comment: Pode fazer o que quiser com as perguntas antigas, quando não tem nada legal na frontpage, fico fuçando nos arquivos do site procurando perguntas interessantes. Mas tal como Marcelo comenta em sua resposta, você tem que acrescentar algo à discussão do problema.

Comment: Quando respondo algumas perguntas tenho certeza que uma resposta nova vai surgir no futuro, que eu não tenho condições de responder completamente agora, ou que a resposta é ampla e seria benéfica para a comunidade. Num dos casos eu marquei a resposta como wiki, mas depois me orientaram a voltar para trás e eu tentar manter a pergunta por enquanto (aproveitei e atualizei uma coisa que lembrei hoje). Mas nem sempre dá para fazer uma destas previsões, ou até melhorar uma resposta que encontrei, até jogo nos comentários quando dá, mas se o cara não atualiza fica chato escrever outra do zero.

Comment: @Jorge B. muito obrigado por citar esta pergunta, é um problema que sempre tive curiosidade de saber, e a resposta atual é bem fácil de seguir.

Comment: valeu pessoal!  a dúvida maior estava nessa questão em permitir ou não responder questões antigas devido a má experiência que tive no SOen, certa vez. Outra dúvida que eu tinha era em relação a postar como comentário ou como resposta. Como comentário ficaria complicado pois o espaço é curto e não permite formação de texto então pensei em colocar como  resposta, porém, a resposta é curta e estaria mais como complemento as outras respostas, o que poderia talvez gerar negativos.

Comment: @DanielOmine, nesse caso você poderia criar um comentário com o complemento da resposta

Comment: Marcelo, se vc ler o meu comentario acima do seu, entenderá.

Answer (score 9):

Desde que a sua resposta venha a acrescentar conteúdo significativo ou informativo a resposta, não acredito que haja problema, isso vale também para perguntas mais antigas onde surgiram novas ferramentas (ou até mesmo ferramentas e/ou recursos que ficaram ociosos) para se resolver um mesmo problema.

Caso queira acrescentar informações ao SOpt, vem muito a calhar, o problema é como [nesse mesmo caso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/75832/14262) que passou, o rapaz, provavelmente novo na rede, tentar solicitar a descriptografia de um `hash MD5` respondendo uma pergunta antiga...

Comment: obrigado. Eu perguntei porque há alguns meses atrás "ousei" em adicionar informação relevante numa pergunta antiga no SOen e recebi uma chuva de downvotes.. Fui forçado a excluir a resposta, infelizmente. Sobre esse rapaz perdido que fez pergunta, realmente tem que remover mesmo.. eu marquei para remover. E sobre a minha resposta, eu queria adicionar sobre rainbow tables. Achei estranho ninguém mencionar esse termo.. Era sobre isso que gostaria de adicionar, mas não sei se receberia downvotes como ocorre no SOen..

Comment: É bom esperar mais algumas respostar, porque não sei bem como e visto pela comunidade, por se tratar de um debate, eu postei a minha opinião rs...

Comment: valeu pelo conselho. Eu já estava quase indo lá responder feito bobo alegre.. rsrsrs

Answer (score 6):

Não há o menor problema em responder perguntas antigas, muito pelo contrário, na verdade o sistema incentiva isso concedendo medalhas para quem responde perguntas bem recebidas pela comunidade, veja:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Além de incentivar a responder, também é incentivado que você edite (por mais que de repente nem saiba a resposta). Veja as medalhas:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui **não temos** o sarcástico troféu "Pá de ouro" que eu já vi em fóruns e acho ridícula.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando você responde uma pergunta você não está simplesmente ajudando a um único indivíduo (o autor da pergunta), mas sim um número absurdo de visitantes anônimos que visitam o site diariamente. De acordo com a própria SE, 90% do tráfego se origina de motores de buscas, daí dá para se ter uma ideia de quantas pessoas um tópico antigo pode estar ajudando.

Ou seja, se você tem algo de útil para acrescentar em uma pergunta antiga, vá em frente.

Comment: kkkkkkkkkkkk - Essa imagem é fantástica.